# iOS - Parsing XML Data Couldn't Get All Data

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

today I want to try parsing an xml data from an URL. I use NSXMLParser to get xml data an process it on my app. Now, the problem is when I try to log the result, I just got one item parsed. Is there any step that I missed..?

What I want is try to get all items on this xml. But, why I only get one item parsed..??? Could anyone help me..?

xml data.

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <channel>
        <generator>Feed Generator</generator>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link>http://m.example.com/index.html</link>
        <description>semua description tentang situs ini</description>
        <language>id-ID</language>
        <pubDate>Thu, 08 Dec 2011 18:00:51 +0700</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 08 Dec 2011 18:00:51 +0700</lastBuildDate>
        <webMaster>me@me.me (Editor)</webMaster>
        <image>
            <title>Image Title/title>
            <url>http://imagelink.com/image.jpg</url>
            <link>http://imagelink.com/imageindex.html</link>
        </image>

        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[Article Title]]></title>
            <link>http://article-example.com</link>
            <pubDate>Thu, 08 Dec 2011 17:23:00 +0700</pubDate>
            <dc:creator>example.com</dc:creator>
            <category><![CDATA[]]></category>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">0000380840</guid>
            <description><![CDATA[article description]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[article content]]></content:encoded>
            <enclosure url="http://imageurl.com/image.jpg" length="10240" type="image/jpg"/>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[Article Title]]></title>
            <link>http://article-example.com</link>
            <pubDate>Thu, 08 Dec 2011 17:23:00 +0700</pubDate>
            <dc:creator>example.com</dc:creator>
            <category><![CDATA[]]></category>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">0000380840</guid>
            <description><![CDATA[article description]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[article content]]></content:encoded>
            <enclosure url="http://imageurl.com/image.jpg" length="10240" type="image/jpg"/>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[Article Title]]></title>
            <link>http://article-example.com</link>
            <pubDate>Thu, 08 Dec 2011 17:23:00 +0700</pubDate>
            <dc:creator>example.com</dc:creator>
            <category><![CDATA[]]></category>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">0000380840</guid>
            <description><![CDATA[article description]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[article content]]></content:encoded>
            <enclosure url="http://imageurl.com/image.jpg" length="10240" type="image/jpg"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is my code.

```
file .h

    NSXMLParser *rssParser;
    NSMutableArray *articles;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *currentElement;
    NSData *xmlFile;


    NSMutableString *elementValue, *feedTitle, *feedDate, *feedDesc, *feedID, *feedEnclosure, *feedContent, *feedLink;

    BOOL errorParsing;
```

.

```
file .m
/////////XML PARSE/////////////
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL{
    NSString *agentString = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.27.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.2.1 Safari/525.27.1";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    [request setValue:agentString forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    xmlFile = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    errorParsing=NO;

    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlFile];
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];

    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];

    [rssParser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError{
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error code %i", [parseError code]];
    NSLog(@"Error parsing XML: %@", errorString);
    NSLog(@"Check your internet connection: %@", errorString);

    errorParsing=YES;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    elementValue = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        feedTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        feedDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        feedContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        feedLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        feedDesc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        feedID = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        feedEnclosure = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([elementValue isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [feedTitle appendString:string];
    }else if ([elementValue isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        [feedLink appendString:string];
    }else if ([elementValue isEqualToString:@"content:encoded"]){
        [feedContent appendString:string];
    }else if ([elementValue isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]){
        [feedDate appendString:string];
    }else if ([elementValue isEqualToString:@"guid"]){
        [feedID appendString:string];
    }else if ([elementValue isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]){
        [feedEnclosure appendString:string];
    }else if ([elementValue isEqualToString:@"description"]){
        [feedDesc appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:feedTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:feedLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:feedDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
        [item setObject:feedContent forKey:@"content:encoded"];
        [item setObject:feedDesc forKey:@"description"];
        [item setObject:feedEnclosure forKey:@"enclosure"];
        [item setObject:feedID forKey:@"guid"];
        [articles addObject:item];
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    if (errorParsing == NO) {

        NSLog(@"ID:%@", feedID);
        NSLog(@"title:%@", feedTitle);
        NSLog(@"date created: %@", feedDate);
        NSLog(@"%@", feedEnclosure);
        NSLog(@"%@", feedContent);

        NSLog(@"XML processing done!");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"error processing xml file");
    }
}
////////////////////////////////
```

.

the result

```
2011-12-08 18:51:18.305 FlipView[1537:f803] ID:0000380840

2011-12-08 18:51:18.306 FlipView[1537:f803] title:Article Title

2011-12-08 18:51:18.307 FlipView[1537:f803] date created: Mon, 08 Dec 2011 17:23:00 +0700

2011-12-08 18:51:18.307 FlipView[1537:f803] 



2011-12-08 18:51:18.308 FlipView[1537:f803] article content

2011-12-08 18:51:18.308 FlipView[1537:f803] XML processing done!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `parserDidEndDocument` is called only once at the end of parsing. You intend to run this code at the end of each item.

EDIT: Sorry thought this was implied. Change your code to this.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:feedTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:feedLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:feedDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
        [item setObject:feedContent forKey:@"content:encoded"];
        [item setObject:feedDesc forKey:@"description"];
        [item setObject:feedEnclosure forKey:@"enclosure"];
        [item setObject:feedID forKey:@"guid"];
        [articles addObject:item];

        NSLog(@"ID:%@", feedID);
        NSLog(@"title:%@", feedTitle);
        NSLog(@"date created: %@", feedDate);
        NSLog(@"%@", feedEnclosure);
        NSLog(@"%@", feedContent);

       }
}
```

Comment: so, is there any solution for me..?